NRF24L01 Module not Working with Raspberry Pi Pico (MicroPython)
I have a Raspberry Pi Pico wired to a NRF24L01 module.
I am trying to send the message "test" from the module, but currently I am simply trying to write the value 0b11 to the register SETUP_AW (const(0x03)) and read it back.
How can I write and read values from registers successfully and ultimately send a message?
I have tried running nrf24l01test.py and nrf24l01.py (with the added lines elif usys.platform == "rp2": cfg = {"spi": 0, "miso": 4, "mosi": 7, "sck": 6, "csn": 14, "ce": 17}) but that always outputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 154, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 40, in master
  File "nrf24l01.py", line 79, in __init__
OSError: nRF24L01+ Hardware not responding

(on line 78 of nrf24l01.py, SETUP_AW = 0)
MicroPython Code:
from machine import SPI, Pin
from micropython import const
import time


spi = SPI(id=0, baudrate=500000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=Pin(6), mosi=Pin(7), miso=Pin(4))

CE_PIN = Pin(17, Pin.OUT)
CSN_PIN = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)

CE_PIN.value(0)  # Disable CE (standby mode for the NRF24L01)
CSN_PIN.value(1)  # Deselect the NRF24L01

R_REGISTER = 0x00  # Read register command
CONFIG_REG = const(0x00)  # Address of the CONFIG register
SETUP_AW = const(0x03)  # Setup register
STATUS_REG = const(0x07)  # Status register

buffer = bytearray(1)


def read_register(register):
    CSN_PIN.value(0)  # Select NRF24L01
    spi.write(bytearray([0x00 | register]))  # Send read command
    spi.readinto(buffer, 1)  # Read response into buffer
    CSN_PIN.value(1)  # Deselect NRF24L01
    return buffer[0]


def write_register(register, value):
    CSN_PIN.value(0)  # Select NRF24L01
    spi.write(bytearray([0x20 | register, value]))  # Send write command and value
    CSN_PIN.value(1)  # Deselect NRF24L01
    time.sleep(0.01)  # Short delay for write to settle

write_register(CONFIG_REG, 0b00001111)
write_register(SETUP_AW, 0b11)

status = read_register(0x07)
print(f"STATUS register after write: 0x{status:02X}")

setup_aw_value = read_register(SETUP_AW)

print(f"Written the value 0x{0b11:02X} ({int(0b11)}) to reg {SETUP_AW}")
print(f"Read the value 0x{setup_aw_value:02X} ({int(setup_aw_value)}) from reg {SETUP_AW}")

Output:
STATUS register after write: 0x01
Written the value 0x03 (3) to reg 3
Read the value 0x01 (1) from reg 3

Pin connections:



NRF24L01 Pin
Raspberry Pi Pico GPIO
Raspberry Pi Pico Physical Pin




CE
17
22


CSN
14
19


SCK
6
9


MOSI
7
10


MISO
4
6



Circuit Diagram:
(The capacitator is 10µF)

Any help is welcome!
